# Export folder and file list from Google Drive to Google Sheet based on date

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-shared-drive

I am currently using the below script to pull folder/file information from a google drive, and list the information into a google sheet.  Works fine.  But I would like to refine it to where it pulls the folder/file based upon the date it was generated.

My situation is such that I have created a tracking log for reports, and data elements within reports.  The tracking log is based on the calendar year.  So Jan 1 of a given year, possibly a handful of reports could be generated.  And by Dec 31st of the respective year, the number of reports is in the 300-400 range.  When the tracking log is updated it, clears the entire sheet, and systematically re-pulls everything that was there, and adds anything new.  By the time we get to 300-400 reports that pull process takes 10-15 minutes.  I use a created button ("Update") to run the script.

My vision is to have the aforementioned button generate the most recent date that the script was run, setValue in a cell (say, G2), and then base the next pull for any reports added since the date in G2.  Hopefully, that way, it only pulls the newest additions, appends that information (in the next rows), and does not erase and re-pull all the information that was already there.

```
//Set folder ID
var folderId = 'ID OF FOLDER IN GOOGLE DRIVE HERE';
 
/*// Main function 1: List all folders, & write into the current sheet.
function listFolders(){
  getFolderTree(folderId, false);
};
*/
// Main function 2: List all files & folders, & write into the current sheet.
function listAll(){
  getFolderTree(folderId, true); 
};

// Get Folder Tree
function getFolderTree(folderId, listAll) {
  try {
    // Get folder by id
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    
    // Initialise the sheet
    var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SHEET NAME HERE');
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.appendRow(["Full Path", "Name", "Date", "URL", "Last Updated", "Description", "Size"]);
    
    // Get files and folders
    getChildFolders(parentFolder.getName(), parentFolder, data, sheet, listAll);
    
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
};

// Get the list of files and folders and their metadata in recursive mode
function getChildFolders(parentName, parent, data, sheet, listAll) {
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
  
  // List folders inside the folder
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    // Logger.log("Folder Name: " + childFolder.getName());
    data = [ 
      parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(),
      childFolder.getName(),
      childFolder.getDateCreated(),
      childFolder.getUrl(),
      childFolder.getLastUpdated(),
      childFolder.getDescription(),
      childFolder.getSize()
    ];
    // Write
    sheet.appendRow(data);
    
    // List files inside the folder
    var files = childFolder.getFiles();
    while (listAll & files.hasNext()) {
      var childFile = files.next();
      // Logger.log("File Name: " + childFile.getName());
      data = [ 
        parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName() + "/" + childFile.getName(),
        childFile.getName(),
        childFile.getDateCreated(),
        childFile.getUrl(),
        childFile.getLastUpdated(),
        childFile.getDescription(),
        childFile.getSize()
      ];
      // Write
      sheet.appendRow(data);
    }
    
    // Recursive call of the subfolder
    getChildFolders(parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(), childFolder, data, sheet, listAll);  
  }
};
```

As you can see, I commented out "Main Function 1" as I don't use it.  Can I put a date stipulation within this script, and eliminate the sheet.clear so any new information is just appended at the bottom of the pre-existing rather than being re-pulled?

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

### You can do by using [searchFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams) instead of `getFiles()`

Here, you can specify [query parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms) like e.g the date.

Sample code snippet:

```js
 ...
// make sure the date is in the format "yyyy-MM-dd"
var date = sheet.getRange("G2").getValue();
var files = childFolder.searchFiles('modifiedDate > "' + date + '"');
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var childFile = files.next();
  ...
}
...
```

- If you would only like to get files from new folders, you can use the method [searchFolders()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfoldersparams) in the same way
- If you do need to sort your files sorted by folder, you can apply the method `searchFiles()` directly on `parent` or even the whole `DriveApp`:

```
var files = parent.searchFiles('modifiedDate > "' + date + '"');
```

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('modifiedDate > "' + date + '"');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time, and for the response.  Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work.  As it stands, my script now does not pull anything.  Guessing it is more my lack of coding skill.

Comment: To find the error source, can you test a simplified version fo your code? A function that only contains the code snippet I provided and the necessary variables (sheet, childFolder). Log the value of `date` and make sure it is of the correct format ([ RFC 3339](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339), e.g. `"2021-01-19"`). Log something within the `while loop` to see if a file has been found.